# Cannot map JSON objects to Realm

Tags: ios, swift2, realm, alamofire, swifty-json

**UPDATE 2**
I've tried to handle the migration errors by adding an auto-wipe script but I'm being thrown an error

> Expected declaration

[image: Error thrown by adding script to App delegate]

**UPDATE 1**

I've tried replacing `(response: Response<Particulars, NSError>)` with `(response: Response<AnyObject, NSError>)` and I am getting this error at `let realm = try! Realm()`

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error

[image: Fatal error thrown]

This is my POST request:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import RealmSwift
import ObjectMapper
import AlamofireObjectMapper


class Login {
init(userName: String, passWord: String) {
Data.sharedInstance.userName = userName
Data.sharedInstance.passWord = passWord
}
// call this method to login
func getRequest() {
Alamofire.request(.POST, Data.todoEndpoint, parameters: ["username": Data.sharedInstance.userName!, "password": Data.sharedInstance.passWord!])
    .responseJSON { (response: Response<AnyObject, NSError>) in
        if let result = response.result.value
        {
            let value = JSON(result)
               let realm = try! Realm()
               do{
                  try realm.write{
                      realm.add(result as! Object, update: true)
                                 }
                 }
                 catch let err as NSError {
                        print("Error with realm: " + err.localizedDescription)
                    }                        
        }
        else
        {
            print("JSON data is nil.")
        }

 }
 }
 }
```

---

### Old Post

I have a JSON response as follows which I can get via a post request using Alamofire. I now want to map my data to a database in Realm using `AlamofireObjectMapper` but I am being thrown this error

> Cannot convert value of type '(Response)->()' to expected 
>   argument type 'Response->Void'

[image: Error thrown]

```
{
 "name" : "Jonny Walker",
 "api_token" : "qwertyuiop1234567890",
 "profile_picture" : "http:default_profile_picture.jpg",
 "id" : 10,
 "email" : "jwalker@gmail.com"
 "username" : "jonny"
}
```

How do I fix this issue?

**This is my POST request**

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, Data.todoEndpoint, parameters: ["username": Data.sharedInstance.userName!, "password": Data.sharedInstance.passWord!])
.responseJSON { (response: Response<Particulars, NSError>) in
  var errorFound = Bool()
  var errorMessage = String()
  if let result = response.result.value
  {
    let value = JSON(result)
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
      for particular in result {
        realm.add(particular,update: true)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**This is where I initialise my Realm objects**

```
class Particulars: Object, Mappable {
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var email = ""
  dynamic var id = 0
  dynamic var profilePicture = ""
  dynamic var username = ""
  dynamic var apiToken = ""
  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
  }
  //Impl. of Mappable protocol
  required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
    self.init()
  }
  func mapping(map: Map) {
    id    <- map["id"]
    name <- map["name"]
    email <- map["email"]
    profilePicture <- map["profile_picture"]
    username <- map["username"]
    apiToken <- map["api_token"]
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second part of your question, regarding the migration error. You're getting the error because you've changed your object definitions and they no longer match what's stored in the Realm database. You will need to handle cleanly migrating from one version to the next. Or, if your data is just cached server data, and doesn't need to be persisted for the user since it can be recreated, (or you're in Debug/Testing mode), you can add this to your AppDelegate (at the top of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions...` before you do anything with Realm):

```
    // Auto wipe Realm store if schema has changed
    do {
        let _ = try Realm()
    }
    catch {
        DataController.deleteRealmFilesAtPath(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
    }
```

And then, in your `DataController` class, include this `static` method:

```
static func deleteRealmFilesAtPath(fileURL: NSURL) {
    guard let path = fileURL.path else { return }
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    guard fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path) else { return }

    do {
        try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(path)
        try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(path + ".lock")
        try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(path + ".note")
    }
    catch {
        print("Unable to delete Realm files: \(error)")
    }
}
```

This will wipe the old database files on app launch if the schema has changed. Of course, you'll lose any data in there as well, so you can only use this in some cases.

Comment: Hi @Dave I can't seem to be able to add the do { } catch { } to my AppDelegate. Do you know how I can fix it? Also, when you mentioned the  DataController class, are you referring to  the class where I use realm.write and realm.add? (see updated post)

Comment: do/catch should be fine in the AppDelegate, just make sure it's in your `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool` method. And the DataController can be any class you're using to group your data functions, it could even be your AppDelegate if you don't have a dedicated data class. Update: Saw your update, you need to move your do/catch down into the method, where you have `// Override...`

Comment: I'm getting a "Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x10c127178) to 'RealmSwift.Object' (0x10bc7f770)." at my let realm = try! Realm() line. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: Sure here's a link to my code https://codeshare.io/xkjul (lines 66- 81) and the code where I mapped the data https://codeshare.io/1oQw9

Comment: Ok, first, remove the `!` from `try` (line 69). It's inside the `do` closure, so it will be handled by the `catch` closure if it fails. Next, avoid using `!` everywhere. Try to never use it. Convert your code to check the types, i.e., `as? Object`. Check before feeding it to `realm.add` for example. It looks like `user` is actually a `Dictionary`, not an `Object` hence your crash.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, your completion block needs to take a `Response<AnyObject, NSError>`, not a `Response<Particulars, NSError>`.

Comment: if I were to replace Particulars with AnyObject, how would I be able to link the Particulars class with my POST request?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your update, when you make changes to Realm, you will need to uninstall the app and re-install. That should get rid of your migration error.